# Sql server - Replicating a large database view as table with updated copy of data

Tags: sql-server

We have legacy system with an extensively large ViewListProjects database view which has quite many columns, underlying views, tables and calculated columns.

Thats makes querying this view very slow.

For example this query below is taking two minutes

```
SELECT * FROM    ViewListProjects Where ProjectId = 1245
```

I am looking for a solution to replicate database view as a table with updated copy of data with in database and possibly outside database as well.

Data copy in replica table do not need to be instantly updated even data it could fine to keep "24 hours" old copy of data could possibly work.

Do you have any suggestions how can we replicate a database view as table with updated copy of data from view.

So could we possibly have a job that runs in night to keep data updated.

As this is our legacy system so we dont want to to spend much time on improvements in database architecture because of certain reasons for example a new system has already replaced this database system as future application.

We thought to rebuild it as materilised/Indexed view but it is taking alot of time and has certain limitations.

I guess "linked servers" could be possibly used for this to replicate view to a table? I tried to find solution using linked servers but couldnt find any usefull for the match of our requirement.

As little "contrary" to linked servers right now we need to only to replicate data within current database but there is a possibility that in near future we might need to replicate this view in an external database of another system as well.

Comment: Could you create a table with matching schema and simply `insert into select * from` on a schedule eg during low activity overnight, if that's relevant?

Comment: @Stu Yes probably your solution seems quite good. We are already working on to implement it. Thanks